# Avoiding re-renders for sibling React components with array of state stored in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm rendering a series of frames from a video, each in their own component. The frames are stored as a state within a parent component called Timeline.

Since I need to manipulate elements of the array of frames from the children components, I pass in callback functions which have the index `i` with a closure. To avoid changes in individual frames affecting all frames, I've used the `memo` higher-order component around each `Frame`.

Nevertheless, I've found that any time I select a frame, all of the frames are re-rendered. Using the `whyDidyouUpdate` hook (https://usehooks.com/useWhyDidYouUpdate/), I've pinpointed it down to my callback changing on each render.

I tried doing `onClick={useCallback(() => selectFrame(i), [])}`, but instead, the frame simply does not change colors, indicating to me that this has somehow impeded the callback from properly functioning.

```
let Frame = memo(({frame, ...}) => (
    <img style={{border: frame.selected ? "green" : "red";}} />
);

let Timeline = () => {

    let [frames, setFrames] = useState([
        { id: "00000", selected: True, ...more image information },
        { id: "00001", selected: True, ...more image information },
        { id: "00002", selected: True, ...more image information },
    ]);

    let selectFrame = (i) => {
        let newFrames = [...frames];
        newFrames[i].mask = base64;
        setFrames(newFrames);
    }

    return (
        <div>
        {frames.map((f, i) => (
            <Frame
                frame={f}
                key={f.id}
                onClick={() => selectFrame(i)}
            />
        )}
        </div>
    ));
}
```

Any suggestions for the correct way to handle this? Thanks

EDIT: Drew's solution below pointed me in the correct direction. The proper syntax is:

```
const selectFrame = (i) => useCallback(() =>
    setFrames(frames.map((f, j) => (
        (i === j) ? {...f, selected: !f.selected} : f
    ))), []);
```

You need to have a different memoized callback for each function.

Comment: I am leaning towards this is just proper React behavior. You are passing down a callback and when it fires it causes a rerender in the components it was passed into. 

If you want to completely avoid this you may just need to lift the state/behavior you are manipulating with the callback to the most common ancestor/parent

Comment: Potentially if it is a shared stateful behavior (not Contextual) maybe it can become a Custom Hook...

Answer (score 0):

The `memo` HOC simply does a shallow comparison of props, each time the `frames` are mapped a *new* `onClick` callback is created. Convert to a curried callback that encloses the index and returns, and uses a functional state update, and memoize the callback using the `useCallback` hook.

```
const Timeline = () => {

    const [frames, setFrames] = useState([
        { id: "00000", selected: True, ...more image information },
        { id: "00001", selected: True, ...more image information },
        { id: "00002", selected: True, ...more image information },
    ]);

    const selectFrame = useCallback(index => () => {
        setFrames(frames => frames.map((frame, i) => i === index ? {
          ...frame,
          mask: base64;
        } : frame));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
        {frames.map((f, i) => (
            <Frame
                frame={f}
                key={f.id}
                onClick={selectFrame(i)}
            />
        )}
        </div>
    ));
}
```

Comment: It worked! Could you elaborate on why the state update needs to be functional?

Comment: @CristobalSciutto I suppose it *doesn't* absolutely need to be a functional state update but it's certainly a pattern that leads to less buggy code. If there's *any* chance two or more state updates can be enqueued in a single render cycle (i.e. two frames' `onClick` quickly clicked) then with plain updates all the enqueued updates use the same *current* state versus the state from the previous update computation. I should have also called it out that `newFrames[i].mask = base64;` is considered a state mutation, hence creating a new frame object `{ ...frame, mask: base64 }`.